# Can we change the photograph of a portal?

Tags: ingress

Is there a way to change the photograph of a portal? I know that we can submit new photos for a portal and sometimes I see that portal photos do change but I don't know how they are being changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Portal photos do have a "like" button (the thumbs up icon) beneath them. The most liked photo is shown on portals. All players have a vote on photos. You can't dislike a photo but you can take back your former vote by repressing the "like" button. A former vote is represented with the same icon drawn with a yellowish contour.

I don't know the process with two photos having the same count of likes. I guess in that case the oldest one is being shown.

Comment: Is this supposed to be part of your question or did you just ask something to answer yourself to get rep? :D

Comment: I did it to enrich the ingress tag on Arqade. I find this community to be much richer in both content and the process itself than many other platforms like reddit, google's own help center etc. I'm trying to push up the awareness for ingress in here by providing answers to questions untouched by other platforms.

Comment: And of course I would like to get some rep in the process ;)

Comment: I wish there were more ppl active on the RIFT tag too :( and I wish I could get some rep too :D